# Subscribing to job collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, jobs, job-scheduling

I am using `meteor-job-collections` (https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection).

When I subscribe to my job collection just to output my completed jobs, it is very slow loading.

Isn't the collection just a simple collection or does it do something since it loads so slowly?

All my jobs are completed, so it should show the documents in the collection just as fast as with every other collection.

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without the source code